# Show that $\sin(45^\circ+\alpha)=\cos(45^\circ-\alpha)$ and $\cos(45^\circ+\alpha)=\sin(45^\circ-\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

Show that if $\alpha\in[0^\circ;45^\circ]:\sin(45^\circ+\alpha)=\cos(45^\circ-\alpha)$ and $\cos(45^\circ+\alpha)=\sin(45^\circ-\alpha).$

I tried to use the unit circle, but I am not sure how to draw the angles $\alpha, 45^\circ+\alpha$ and $45^\circ-\alpha.$ I have noticed $45^\circ+\alpha\le90^\circ$ and $45^\circ-\alpha\ge0^\circ.$
Can I use any other approaches? Why do we have restrictions on $\alpha$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Double angle formula?

Comment: The identities you wrote are actually true for any $\alpha$ I believe.

Comment: Do you know the [angle addition formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)?

Comment: We know that $\cos(90 - \theta) = \sin(\theta)$. So, apply this to $\cos(45-\alpha)=\cos(90-(45+\alpha))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\sin \theta = \cos(90^\circ -\theta) \\ \cos\theta =\sin(90^\circ -\theta)$$ The range of $\alpha$ is irrelevant, as this identity holds for all $\theta\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Incidentally, this is why cosine is called cosine—it is the sine of the co-angle.

Comment: @Joe Co is short for complimentary, I believe?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's funny how the etymology of a term in mathematics can help you understand it better. I only recently learned that $\arcsin(x)$ is called so because you are trying to find the arc (in the unit circle) which has a vertical coordinate of $x$.

Comment: compl*e*mentary

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ah of course

Comment: Thank you for the response! I see it now. How did you come up with this idea (using exactly these identities)?

Comment: @nicoledobreva I saw that $45-\alpha$ and $45+\alpha$ add up to $90$. :)

Comment: @nicoledobreva Notice that the second identity follows from the first. If we know that $\sin(45+\alpha)=\cos(45-\alpha)$ then, replacing $\alpha$ with $-\alpha$, we get $\cos(45+\alpha)=\sin(45-\alpha)$.

Comment: Co-functions of all complementary valued angles are equal.

Comment: @Narasimham That directly follows from the first identity.

Comment: Yes, for ***all*** circular trig functions.

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, that’s what I assumed you meant by co-functions.

Answer (score 0):

$HINT$:You should know that $\sin(x)\times \sin(y)=\frac{\cos(x+y)-\cos(x-y)}{-2}$ and  $\sin(x)\times \cos(y)=\frac{\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)}{2}$

so, try to multiply and divide the former by $\sin(45+a)$ and the latter by $\cos(45+a)$

for the former:

$\frac{\sin(45+a)\times \sin(45+a)}{\sin(45+a)}=[\frac{\cos(90+2a)-\cos(0)}{-2}]=\sin(45+a)\times \cos(45-a)=[\frac{\sin(90)+\sin(2a)}{2}]$

so,$\sin(2a)=\sin(2a)$

The second for yours :))